# Infinity value in a dataframe spark / scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with infinity values . How can I replace it by 0.0.

I tried that but thoesn't work .

`val Nan=  dataframe_final.withColumn("Vitesse",when(col("Vitesse").isin(Double.NaN,Double.PositiveInfinity,Double.NegativeInfinity),0.0))`

**Example of dataframe**

```
--------------------
|    Vitesse       |
--------------------
| 8.171069002316942|
|  Infinity        |
| 4.290418664272539|
|16.19811830014666 |
|                  |
```

**How can I replace "Infinity by 0.0" ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct using **`when() .otherwise()`**

- add the missing `otherWise` statement to get Vitesse values as is if value is not in **`Infinity,-Infinity,NaN`**.

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq(("8.171".toDouble),("4.2904".toDouble),("16.19".toDouble),(Double.PositiveInfinity),(Double.NegativeInfinity),(Double.NaN)).toDF("Vitesse")
df.show()
//+---------+
//|  Vitesse|
//+---------+
//|    8.171|
//|   4.2904|
//|    16.19|
//| Infinity|
//|-Infinity|
//|      NaN|
//+---------+

df.withColumn("Vitesse", when(col("Vitesse").isin(Double.PositiveInfinity,Double.NegativeInfinity,Double.NaN),0.0).
otherwise(col("Vitesse"))).
show()
//+-------+
//|Vitesse|
//+-------+
//|  8.171|
//| 4.2904|
//|  16.19|
//|    0.0|
//|    0.0|
//|    0.0|
//+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> df.withColumn("Vitesse", when(col("Vitesse").equalTo(Double.PositiveInfinity),0.0).otherwise(col("Vitesse")))
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Vitesse: double]

scala> res1.show
+-----------------+
|          Vitesse|
+-----------------+
|8.171069002316942|
|              0.0|
|4.290418664272539|
+-----------------+
```

You can try like above.